# dnsmasq is providing the same IP to two different clients

Tags: networking, dhcp, dnsmasq

Consider the following dnsmasq config (used for a VPN server which is on a tap interface tap_vpn0):

```
dhcp-ignore-names
dhcp-generate-names

dhcp-sequential-ip
interface=tap_vpn0
dhcp-range=192.168.120.50,192.168.120.150,255.255.255.0,5m
dhcp-option=3,192.168.120.1

log-dhcp
leasefile-ro
```

With this config two different clients (different MAC addresses, different names, but same hostname) are getting the exactly same IP address! Even if it is already leased, it still is offered to the second one!

Check theese logs: [dnsmasq logs](https://pastebin.com/55bnn8hQ)

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: during experimentation I:

- Added dhcp-ignore-names
- Added dhcp-generate-names after the ignore
- Removed dhcp-authoritative
- Added dhcp-sequential-ip
- Added leasefile-ro

Of course restarting dnsmasq each time. The problem didn't changed a bit! Just the handed IP was different, but was always exactly the same for both clients.